# Gerar PDF pelo PHP?

Tags: php, impressão, boleto

Consegui gerar o boleto no meu site junto com o projeto BoletoPHP, e os dados do banco.

Agora, quando ele vai imprimir no CHROME ele sai com o código de barras errado, isso é até uma issue relatada: https://github.com/CobreGratis/boletophp/issues/103.

Fato curioso é que é só no chrome. Pensando em uma alternativa, eu pensei em Salvar em PDF, e então abrir pelo Acrobat e funcionou.

**Como eu consigo, ao gerar o PDF na página em PHP já fazer o download do arquivo como PDF em vez de simplesmente exibí-lo?** Caso isso não seja possível, se alguém tiver alguma outra ideia/alternativa viável e que ajude eu agradeço

Comment: Pelo que eu vi [nesse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php) é a melhor lib, tem bastante suporte. Conheço mais o textsharp do c#, mas esse vai resolver o que você precisa.
[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/):<br>
-[Tutoriais](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php)<br>
-[Scripts](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Como o Leonardo já disse, o FPDF vai resolver o seu caso. Ela é fácil de se usar e tem bastante tutorial na internet. Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
require_once("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf= new FPDF("P","pt","A4");
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('arial','B',18);
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"Relatório",0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"","B",1,'C');
$pdf->Ln(50);

//cabeçalho da tabela 
$pdf->SetFont('arial','B',14);
$pdf->Cell(130,20,'Coluna 1',1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(140,20,'Coluna 2',1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(130,20,'Coluna 3',1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(160,20,'Coluna 4',1,1,"L");

//linhas da tabela
$pdf->SetFont('arial','',12);
for($i= 1; $i <10;$i++){
$pdf->Cell(130,20,"Linha ".$i,1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(140,20,rand(),1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(130,20,rand(),1,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(160,20,rand(),1,1,"L");
}
$pdf->Output("arquivo.pdf","D");
```

E para fazer o download em vez de exibir é só colocar essa linha de código no final.

```
$pdf->Output("arquivo.pdf","D");
```

Esse exemplo retirei daqui: http://www.botecodigital.info/php/criando-arquivos-pdf-com-php-e-classe-fpdf/